# regex for input number and . allowing commas

Tags: regex

I have a form submission where I have the person enter an amount.

I have it working fine to reject $ and anything but numbers but it is allowing commas and i cannot seem to get it to stop doing this.

The code is ColdFusion but it is not a CF issue but a RegEx one.

```
 <cfinput type="Text" 
  name="sp_price" 
  value="0" 
  message="Add-on Price - Numbers Only" 
  validate="regular_expression" 
  pattern="^[0-9].*$" required="No" size="5">
```

Accepts 1000 1000.00 and 1,000.00 and 1,000 and the I don't want the commas accepted.

Thanks in advance
andy

Comment: A dot means *any* character

Comment: Hi PeeHaa. Please look at my reply to Michael below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude characters, the format would be `[^,]`

Example:

```
pattern="^([0-9]|[^,$\w])*$"
```

Edit: excludes dollar and word characters https://regex101.com/r/tK5zU7/1

Comment: I guess what confuses  me is what works in one RegEx fails in another.

I use "^[().+\d -]{1,20}$" for telephone numbers so any international number will work no matter how they enter it with () . + - etc. I really don't care what the number code is and if it matches their country. Just protecting the site. This code will not accept commas.

Comment: This allows anything but a comma instead of only numbers. Also `[0-9]|[^,]` doesn't make much sense, because `[^,]` already matches `[0-9]`

Comment: I tested Michaels RegEx thoroughly in my page trying to get past it and it worked perfect every time so as usual with RegEx I am often stumped. If you are discussing the phone number RegEx I just tried it again and it will not accept anything but what I want it to.

Comment: Did find one minor change needed in Michaels RegEx: ^([0-9]|[^,$])*$ keeps out the $.

Comment: So `dfdfkjfdklj` is a valid price?

Comment: @PeeHaa has a good point regarding the `or not comma`, which will include any character other than the comma. I've edited my answer to exclude word characters `\w` and I included your change (@Andy) to exclude the dollar sign `$`

Answer (score 1):

You can make your regex more restrictive like this:

```
"^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"
```

which will only allow integers or decimal numbers but no comma or `$` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`^\d*(\.\d{2})?$`

- 1000 - matches
- 1000.00 - matches
- 1,000.00 - does not match
- 1,000 - does not match

It matches full numbers of any length and optionally decimals of length two. Try the link below.

https://regex101.com/r/kN8zL0/1